# Is it possible to turn on PC without CPU, RAM and HDD

Tags: hard-drive, cpu

Is it possible to turn on PC without CPU, RAM and HDD ?
If not, do I need CPU connected? 
The problem that I am actually solving is that I cannot turn my PC on and most probably it is an issue of power supply.

Comment: What. Without a CPU, the computer has no way to process anything, and cannot operate. Without RAM you'll get to POST and Memtest before it politely tells you it can't work, and without a HDD you just can't boot into anything, but no CPU = no Computer. If you want to test a PSU get a second one and swap them.

Comment: Agree with @tjennings if you want to test the PSU you can do it [manually](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/ht/power-supply-test-multimeter.htm)

Comment: In general, no.  If you disconnect all loads the power supply will not start reliably (ie, you need a "dummy load"), plus you need to know which pins to short to turn it on.  And, of course, you need at least a simple voltmeter to see if it's actually on.

Comment: Hey! But I had a burnt mo-bo (capacitor problem) and after turning the PC on the fan on the PSU was still spinning, even though it didn't see any CPU or RAM obviously. If your PSU is alive it should be spinning, because the actual power button just short-circuits the pins on the PSU's main mo-bo connector. You can short-circuit the green wire (16th pin) and any ground(black) wire on the connector to check if the PSU is alive. And then use a multimeter to check the voltage levels

Answer (score 3):

The mainboard should power on but you won't get a display or anything.  The fans may run at full speed since it's the CPU that controls that.  You might hear something like a continuous beep.  It's been awhile since I've tried this.

Answer (score 3):

You need

- RAM
- CPU
- Motherboard
- Power

That's it.  You can take everything else out.  To mess with the BIOS, you might want a keyboard (or mouse depending on the age of your BIOS)